# Async Task in Android

Tags: android, android-listview, android-asynctask, arrays

I am having trouble with my ArrayAdapter now... I get the error "The constructor ArrayAdapter(VideoPlay.ShowTitlesTask, int, int, ArrayList) is undefined." What am I doing wrong?

The problem is in the class ShowTitlesTask

```
package com.aer.illbehonest;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;

import net.sf.json.JSONArray;
import net.sf.json.JSONObject;
import net.sf.json.JSONSerializer;

import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class VideoPlay extends Activity {   
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_video_play);

        new ShowTitlesTask().execute("");
    }

    class ShowTitlesTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, ArrayList<String>> {

    ArrayList<String> titlesList;

    @Override
protected ArrayList<String> doInBackground(String... args) {

    URL jsonURL = null;
    try {
           jsonURL = new URL("http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/illbehonest/uploads?v=2&alt=jsonc");
        } catch (MalformedURLException e3) {
            e3.printStackTrace();
        }
            URLConnection jc = null;
            try {
                jc = jsonURL.openConnection();
            } catch (IOException e2) {
                e2.printStackTrace();
            }
            InputStream is = null;
            try {
                is = jc.getInputStream();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            String jsonTxt = null;
            try {
                jsonTxt = IOUtils.toString(is);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            JSONObject json = (JSONObject) JSONSerializer.toJSON(jsonTxt);

            JSONObject jdata = json.getJSONObject("data");

            JSONArray jentry = jdata.getJSONArray("items");
            for (int entryNumber = 0; entryNumber<=25; entryNumber++){
                    JSONObject entry = jentry.getJSONObject(entryNumber);
                    titlesList.add(entry.getString("title"));
            }

            return titlesList;
    }
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<String> result) {
        ListView listView = (ListView)VideoPlay.this.findViewById(R.id.videolist);

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String> (this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, titlesList);
        titlesList.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you will need to return an ArrayList from  doInBackground and add ArrayList to ListView in onPostExecute because this method call when doInBackground execution completes. create your AsyncTask as :

```
   private class GetTitlesTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, ArrayList<String>> {
   Activity activity;
        ArrayList<String> titlesList;
       public GetTitlesTask(Activity activity){
           this.activity=activity;
       }
          @Override
          protected void onPreExecute() {
            // show progress bar here
          }
        @Override
        protected ArrayList<String> doInBackground(String... args) {

             titlesList=new ArrayList<String>;

              // get titles here and add to titlesList ArrayList

             return titlesList; //<< return titlesList ArrayList
         }
        @Override
         protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<String> result) {

            // set result ArrayList as datasouce to Adapter here
             ListView listview=
                (ListView)activity.findViewById(R.id.videolist);
         }
     }
```

and start this GetTitlesTask AsyncTask from UI as:

```
new GetTitlesTask(Your_Current_Activity.this).execute("");
```

to known more about AsyncTask see

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: when I try to set ListView listview to findViewById(R.id.videolist) I get an error saying "The method findViewById(int) is undefined for the type ShowTitlesTask"

Comment: @ZacCanoy : make sure `ShowTitlesTask` is inner class of an Activity if yes then use `ListView listview=(ListView)your_Activity.this.findViewById(R.id.videolist);` and if ShowTitlesTask is not an inner class of Activity then you will need to pass Context of Activity to non Activity class

Comment: what do you mean by inner class? I'm a beginner. I tried it "as is" and it gave me "No enclosing instance of the type VideoPlay **(my activity)** is accessible in scope"

Comment: @ZacCanoy : where you are creating AsyncTask class in same class where u have your ListActivity or in separate class ?

Comment: Separate .java files. If that is what you mean.

Comment: Don't I need to use an array list adapter?

Comment: @ZacCanoy : if you are still facing issue then post your relevant code

Comment: I'm sorry I will do that tomorrow because my computer currently has no internet connection. Please continue to follow this , I will post my code.

Comment: 'public class VideoPlay extends Activity { 
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_video_play);
            
            new ShowTitlesTask().execute("");
        }'

Comment: @ZacCanoy : plz edit code of VideoPlay Activity and ShowTitlesTask class   in your question to solve issue quick

Comment: @ZacCanoy : problem solved or not if yes then mark it as answer if my answer help u solving current issue

Answer (score 0):

As you are using `AsyncTask` you should update your ui from `onPostExecute` method. Set the adapter here and you are ready.

```
protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
titlesList.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);                      
};
```